# Passing Object Variable from List to a Foreach Loop error

Tags: c#, ssis

I am new to SSIS and am facing an interesting issue. I am passing a list to an object variable and feeding a foreach container with this object since it holds several file paths for files. This is my C# code:

```
 FileInfo[] excelFiles = di.GetFiles("*.xlsx");
        ExcelModel model = new ExcelModel();
        if (excelFiles.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach(var item in excelFiles)
            {
                //recent edit
                model = new ExcelModel();
                model.ExcelFilePath = item.FullName;
                list.Add(model);
            }

        }
        Dts.Variables["ExcelFilesList"].Value = list;
```

ExcelModel is...

```
class ExcelModel
    {
        public string ExcelFilePath { get; set; }
    }
```

I am getting the following error: Error: ForEach Variable Mapping number 1 to variable "User::ExcelFilePath" cannot be applied.

Any help would be fantastic I've been stuck for a while now.

EDIT: In the Foreach in Variable Mapping I have a ExcelFilePath string that is mapped to index 0

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a script task to generate this list of files versus using the out of the box Foreach (file) Enumerator?

Answer (score 2):

You are just editing the same object and adding it to the list.
you should create a new object each time.

```
FileInfo[] excelFiles = di.GetFiles("*.xlsx");
        ExcelModel model = new ExcelModel();
        if (excelFiles.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach(var item in excelFiles)
            {
                model = new ExcelModel();
                model.ExcelFilePath = item.FullName;
                list.Add(model);
            }

        }
        Dts.Variables["ExcelFilesList"].Value = list;
```

Or:

```
FileInfo[] excelFiles = di.GetFiles("*.xlsx");
        if (excelFiles.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach(var item in excelFiles)
                list.Add(new ExcelModel(){ExcelFilePath = item.FullName});
        }
        Dts.Variables["ExcelFilesList"].Value = list;
```

Or:

```
FileInfo[] excelFiles = di.GetFiles("*.xlsx");
            if (excelFiles.Length > 0)
                    list.AddRange(excelFiles.Select(e=> item ExcelModel{ExcelFilePath = item.FullName}));
            Dts.Variables["ExcelFilesList"].Value = list;
```

Comment: Hi Ashkan, I tried this method as well earlier and tried your exact code but I am getting the same error. thanks

Comment: Tried the newer method you posted and its failing as well, same error.

Comment: what is the type of `list` in `list.Add(new ExcelModel(){ExcelFilePath = item.FullName});` the must be something about its declaration

Comment: It's this:  List<ExcelModel> list = new List<ExcelModel>();

Comment: @LordRelix I edited the answer. please try this one too. but the problem must be somewhere else in you declarations.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the location of the variable, instead you should really use `Linq` -- it dramatically simplifies this for you. It seems as though, based on the answer to your own question that you really just needed a `List<string>`, here is the `Linq` for that.

```
 FileInfo[] excelFiles = di.GetFiles("*.xlsx");
 if (excelFiles.Length > 0)
 {
     Dts.Variables["ExcelFilesList"].Value =
         excelFiles.Select(file => file.FullName).ToList();
 }
```

Comment: This is BBIS2008, am having some trouble getting the Linq reference in here =/.

Answer (score 0):

After some dabbling I figured the problem... I changed my code to this:

```
        List<string> newList = new List<string>();
        FileInfo[] excelFiles = di.GetFiles("*.xlsx");
        if (excelFiles.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in excelFiles)
            {
                newList.Add(item.FullName);
            }
        }
        Dts.Variables["ExcelFilesList"].Value = newList;
```